# How to resize HTML widget using saveWidget in htmlwidgets R?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I use `saveWidget` function in `htmlwidgets` to save HTML widgets in R. I got the saved HTML files with width 960 and height 500. 
I am pretty sure that I can resize the widget within `knitrOptions` parameters but I can not find out the list of the parameters to resize the widget. 
I have tried:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(htmlplot, file, knitrOptions = list(width = 1200, height = 700)
```

I also have tried using `fig.width`, `defaultWidth`, etc. but none of them are worked.

How could I resize the widget?

Comment: What about `out.width`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem today.
Unfortunately, I didn't find a good solution to this.
I had to change the attribute width of the widget:

```
wid <- ggiraph(ggobj=pl,
               zoom_max=1000,
               tooltip_opacity=0.7,
               tooltip_extra_css="width:300px;background-color:black;color:white;font-family:Sans,Arial",
               width_svg=80,
               height_svg=7,
               width=1)
wid$x$width <- "6000px"
temp_output <- tempfile(tmpdir=getwd(), fileext=".html")
saveWidget(widget=wid, file=basename(temp_output), selfcontained=TRUE,
           knitrOptions=list())
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606653/r-saving-multiple-html-widgets-together thanks!