# How to export DT table to html and preserve all functionality?

Tags: html, r, dt, htmlwidgets

I'm able to export a DT table generated in R/RStudio to HTML using the htmlWidget:saveWidget method. However, the FixedColumns feature is not preserved and becomes very narrow when a term is entered in the search bar.

```
xyz_search_dt <- datatable(
  xyz_search_table_d,
  rownames = FALSE, extensions = 'Buttons', 
  options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                 extensions = 'FixedColumns', 
                 options = list(dom = 't',scrollX = TRUE, 
                                fixedColumns = TRUE),
                 columnDefs = list(list(width= '200px',
                                        targets = "feedback")),
                 dom=('Bfrtip'), buttons = c('excel'),
                 pageLength = table_rows,
                 searchHighlight = TRUE),
  filter = list(position="top"))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(xyz_search_dt, "xyz_search_dt.html")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the code in your question to make it easier to read. Don't forget to also take the [tour] and read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found and seems to work well is to address the widget sizing policy after the fact.

```
dow_search_dt[["sizingPolicy"]][["defaultWidth"]] <- "100%"
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(dow_search_dt, "dow_search_dt.html")
```

Reference:

- [How to resize HTML widget using saveWidget in htmlwidgets R (reopened question)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695258/how-to-resize-html-widget-using-savewidget-in-htmlwidgets-r-reopened-question)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. I use the `mtcars` dataset and everything works well.

```
xyz_search_dt <- DT::datatable((mtcars),
                           rownames = FALSE, 
                           extensions = 'Buttons', 
                           options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, 
                                          extensions = 'FixedColumns', 
                                          options = list(dom = 't', 
                                                         scrollX = TRUE, 
                                                         fixedColumns = TRUE),
                                          columnDefs = list(list(width= '200px',
                                                                 targets = "feedback")), 
                                          dom=('Bfrtip'), 
                                          buttons = c('excel'),
                                          #pageLength = table_rows,
                                          searchHighlight = TRUE),
                           filter=list(position="top"))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(xyz_search_dt, "xyz_search_dt.html")
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: This answer simply reuses my original code with pagination.  I think the problem is with the saveWidget function because the text-oriented search table maintains the fixed-width column when rendered through RStudio's viewer.  However, when saved using saveWidget function and opened as a self-contained HTML file, the fixed-width column functionality does not seem to come along.